# AWS RDP Connection logs out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

So, I have RDP on AWS and only 2 users can use it. If a third user tries to connect one of the connection will log out.
I have t2.large instance, I am not sure how to add more users, Can any one guide me?

Comment: Which database engine are you using? Is this RDS for mysql, oracle or postgres?

Comment: It is a windows instance, sorry forget to mention that.

Comment: I believe you mean Microsoft SQL Server.. correct?

Comment: @SaniaIshaq: When you say windows instance, do you mean you run your database on EC2? In case of AWS RDS you have had to select a database type like Pankaj mentioned. Did you choose MS SQL server? Whichever you choose, did you also add configuration afterwards? By default there is no restriction on the amount of connections made unless you specify for yourself.

Comment: Apologies,  It is typing error I am talking about RDP connection. Windows RDP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is expected. At a time only 2 users are allowed to RDP to your windows EC2 instance. If you want 3 or more people to RDP to your instance then you have to buy Client Access Licenses (CALs).

Reference and solution:

[https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/concurrent-users-windows-ec2-rdp/#:~:text=If%20you%20installed%20the%20Remote,grace%20period%20of%20120%20days](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/concurrent-users-windows-ec2-rdp/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20installed%20the%20Remote,grace%20period%20of%20120%20days).

Comment: Please add all explanation about how to resolve the problem to your answer instead of linking to external ressources